# PHP involving in query and json

Tags: php, json

I wanted to test this json array before putting it in my android studio code but when I test it, it says this error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: _id in C:\wamp64\www\json_comments.php on
>   line 8

and

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in C:\wamp64\www\json_comments.php on line 16

I'm a beginner in PHP and I'm trying to learn to the best I can, so please forgive me if I keep on asking these silly questions.

```
<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
$db = 'employee101';
$S_id = 65;

$sql = "select * from employee_comments where id = $_id;";

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$response = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    array_push($response, array(
        "id" => $row[0],
        "comment" => $row[1],
        "rating" => $row[2],
    ));    
}

echo json_encode(array(
    "server_respo"=>$response,
));

mysqli_close($con);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$S_id = 65;
```

to

```
$_id = 65;
```

added S infront

Comment: Wow thanks! Does it really have to be like that in every '$' sign?

Comment: no you can use $S_id, then you have to pass  $S_id to the query. depends what variable name you are using

Comment: Okay, thanks!, but if I don't want it to be a constant 65, I can use it like this right? When I want it to get the input from others

$_id = $_POST['id'];

Comment: yes, for dynamic value you can take it from post of from anywhere, just make sure the variable name that you are using is used in other places too

Comment: Yep, just waiting for the 15 min marker to click green hehe

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this :

```
$S_id = 65;
```

to:

```
$_id = 65;
```

OR

this:

```
$_id = 65;
```

to:

```
$S_id = 65;
```